# ArrayFormula appending to last row not next empty row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet( ss1) that some of the data coming from another google spreadsheet (ss2). I want to set a formula to one of the columns in ss1, (I have ‘first Name’ and ‘Last Name’ in ss1 that coming from ss2 which has a trigger to fire upon form submission, I need to have ‘full name’ column in ss1 concatenating ‘first name’ and ‘last name’). the formula i used is '=ARRAYFORMULA(G2:G&" "&H2:H) '. But when I apply the formula to the relevant cell, whenever new data comes it appends to the very last row(not after the last row that has actual content) and it does not apply the formula to the cell in the updated row. appreciate if anyone can help me to sort this out.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `IF` statement so the `ARRAYFORMULA` know when the apply the concat between the two columns.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A:A), A:A&" "&B:B, ))
```